# Recover a folder deleted with rm -rf on a XEN host

Tags: xenserver

like the title said...I removed a subfolder in the /var/patch and I should have not. Anyway to get it back?

Thanks!

Comment: I'd strongly suggest using your backups.

Comment: This question is being voted for closure because the author does not show a level of technical understanding or appropriate due diligence in researching the topic that the community judges as being a minimum barrier to participate.

Comment: Jinx, @mdpc!  :D

Comment: In a pool? Format and reinstall, take 15m to be up and running

Answer (score 7):

Restore from backup.  (Sorry.)

Comment: You're _so_ not sorry. :D